# ROS Answers SE migration: CMake Error

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am totally new to ROS and I started install this afternoon. Unfortunately, I have a CMake error  during the installation and I do not know how to fix it.
Does anyone has time to support?
I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I will not paste the complete install prompt but the 2 faults below.

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):

ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
```

Thank to let me know how to fix this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279075/cmake-error/) by [JC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33179/jc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-08**:
We need more info: what exactly are you doing? Installing from src? compiling your own Workspace? Have you chacked what the error msg tells you to?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-08**:\

> I have a CMake error during the installation [..]. I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

With "installation", do you mean basic ROS installation? There are binary packages available for 16.04 (`amd64` and ARM), and those typically don't require any CMake invocations to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I removed ROS and reinstall and it worked, I must have missed a step in the insall.Thanks both for your quick action!

---

Originally posted by [JC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33179/jc/) with karma: 16 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0